# How to Read Data from Firebase and Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I use read_CheckOuts to return the database but the ngFor doesn't work

Here is my code:

crud.service.ts

```
import { AngularFireDatabase} from '@angular/fire/database';

export class CrudService {

constructor(
    private db: AngularFireDatabase
 ) { }

read_CheckOuts() {
return this.db.list('/cart_checkouts');
}
}
```

check-out.component.ts

```
import { CrudService } from '../service/crud.service';

constructor(private crudService: CrudService)

this.crudService.read_CheckOuts().valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
this.cart_checkouts = data.map(e => {
        return {
        this:this.cart_checkouts = this.cart_checkouts 
        };
      })
```

This is how I try to display the read data:

check-out.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let out of cart_checkouts">
        <div>
          <h5>Product Name: {{out.product_name}}</h5>
          <h6>quantity: {{out.quantity}} </h6>
          <p>Price: {{out.product_price}}</p>
          <img src="/assets/images/gallery/{{out.thumbnail}}">
        </div>
</div>
```

My firebase database looks like this:

```
cart_checkouts
-MPuEZ_CAdJ8L8s8FaEG
--checkoutProductName: "Adult Unisex Helmet"
--checkoutProductPrice: 4
--checkoutQuantity: 3
--checkoutThumbnail: "product-4.gif"
```

Comment: Add please error or what displays. How checkouts looks like

Comment: This: "_but the ngFor doesn't work_" is not descriptive enough. You must indicate **why** you feel this way, **what** the actual data is (as Oleksii points out).

Comment: There are 8 entries in cart_checkouts and the page returns 8 blank entries. I editted my post to show how the data from the database is written.

Comment: When I console.log this.cart_checkouts I get an array of objects so I should use JSON.parse(this.cart_checkouts) but I can't use JSON.parse in my map function.

Comment: Can you post the actual structure of the data? It seems the data you’re trying to display in your ngFor doesn’t match with the keys you provided..?

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution:

```
this.crudService.read_CheckOuts().valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
   this.cart_checkouts = data;
  });

 <div *ngFor="let out of cart_checkouts">
        <div>
          <h5>Product Name: {{out.checkoutProductName}}</h5>
          <h6>quantity: {{out.checkoutQuantity}} </h6>
          <p>Price: {{out.checkoutProductPrice}}</p>
          <img src="/assets/images/gallery/{{out.checkoutThumbnail}}">
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
yes easily get data from realtime database..!!!

    getDataFromFirebase(){
       var _this = this;
         var firebase = require('firebase')
         let database = firebase.database()
         return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         const db = database .ref();
         const eventRef = db.child('/Table');
         const query = eventRef;
         query.on('value', snap => {
         snap.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
         var data = childSnapshot.val();
         console.log("data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
     });
   });
  });
}
```